# Regex - Negative Lookahead to match a string with any non-Chinese UTF characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, regex-lookarounds

## Intention

to create a regex which creates a match when there is any character, ASCII, Unicode or otherwise, which does not fall into any of the valid UTF-8 ranges for Chinese characters. The match itself does not matter, but rather that the non-Chinese characters are present. Note that the presence of rare, and unused Chinese characters within the UTF-8 charset is intended also. The function returns None when there is no match, thus indicating that the string passed in was pure Unicode Chinese to the caller function.

## Code

Python 3.8

```
chineseRegexSet = "[\u4E00-\u9FFF]|[\u3400-\u4BDF]|[\u20000-\u2A6DF]|[\u2A700-\u2B73F]|[\u2B740-\u2B81F]|[\u2B820-\u2CEAF]|[\uF900-\uFAFF]|[\u2F800-\u2FA1F]"
def ContainsNonChineseCharacters(hanziWord):
    #negative lookahead
    match = search("(?!" + chineseRegexSet + ")+", hanziWord)
    if match:
        if _DEBUG:
            PrintDebugError(hanziWord)
            PrintDebugError(hanziWord, utfEncode=True)
    else:
        _LOGGER.debug(hanziWord)
        if _DEBUG:
            PrintDebug(hanziWord)
            PrintDebug(hanziWord, utfEncode=True)

    return match
```

### Attempted Regex Solutions

**Interpretation**: any non-chinese character neg. lookahead set, at least once

```
(?![\u4E00-\u9FFF]|[\u3400-\u4BDF]|[\u20000-\u2A6DF]|[\u2A700-\u2B73F]|[\u2B740-\u2B81F]|[\u2B820-\u2CEAF]|[\uF900-\uFAFF]|[\u2F800-\u2FA1F])+
```

**Interpretation**: Any non-singular Chinese character from any UTF set

```
(?![\u4E00-\u9FFF]+|[\u3400-\u4BDF]+|[\u20000-\u2A6DF]+|[\u2A700-\u2B73F]+|[\u2B740-\u2B81F]+|[\u2B820-\u2CEAF]+|[\uF900-\uFAFF]+|[\u2F800-\u2FA1F]+)*
```

### Test Cases

`Case`  Expected Result

`大家好` 0 matches

`00你是谁` >=1 match

`s%%2` >=1 match

`你Привет` >=1 match

**Thank you for your time!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `\u20000` doesn't mean what you think it does. Because `\u` sequences must be exactly 4 digits long, that's refers to `U+2000` and the digit `0`. For characters above 0xFFFF, Python provides `\U`, which must be followed by exactly 8 digits (e.g. `\U00020000`).

---

Secondly,

```
[A-B]|[C-D]|...
```

is best written as

```
[A-BC-D...]
```

---

With the above fix and the above simplification, we have this:

`[\u3400-\u4BDF\u4E00-\u9FFF\uF900-\uFAFF\U00020000-\U0002A6DF\U0002A700-\U0002B73F\U0002B740-\U0002B81F\U0002B820-\U0002CEAF\U0002F800-\U0002FA1F]`

There are two ways of approaching the problem:

1. Does the string contain only characters from that class?

   ```py
   is_just_han = re.search("^[...]*$", str)     # or regex.search
   ```
2. Does the string contain a character from outside of that class?

   ```py
   is_just_han = not re.search("[^...]", str)   # or regex.search
   ```

---

If you use the [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module instead of the re module, you gain access to `\p{Han}` (short for `\p{Script=Han}`) and its negation `\P{Han}` (short for `\P{Script=Han}`). This Unicode property is a close match for the characters you are trying to match. I'll let you determine if it's right for you or not.

```py
is_just_han = regex.search("^\p{Han}*$", str)

is_just_han = regex.search("\P{Han}", str)
```

Comment: Regarding the `\P{Script=Han}`, I'd have to do some extensive testing as I am parsing ancient Chinese dictionaries and that accelerator for the Python regex may not support some of those ranges. I love the cleanness of the expression though, I'll definitely give it a try once I get the regex figured.

Comment: Using the proper library, the difference between regexes what failed the check was .04%, which is more than an acceptable tolerance of error / difference. Thanks alot @ikegami!